# Swift 4: didSelectRowAt delegate not being called

Tags: uitableview, delegates

I know there's a ton of these questions posted but I am at a loss as to why my table delegate method is not being called.

I am declaring the protocols ~ UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource

In Storyboard I have delegate and datasource for the tableview set to my UIViewController.

I have a custom UITableViewCell. Checked that and the tableview, both have UserInteractionEnabled checked.

Datasource method works, table populates with the correct data.

This is my didSelectRowAt method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

This never prints and the breakpoint I have in there never gets hit.

Comment: Does `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` get called?

Comment: No, it doesn't get called either.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your delegate is non-null in your table view? Assuming it's set, is the table view in editing mode? Delete methods will not be called if isEditing is true unless allowsSelectionDuringEditing is also true.

Comment: do you have any gesture recognisers on your view that could be receiving the touches instead?

Comment: The issue may in IB with the properties of the UITableView : Selection set to No Selection

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
  print("your content = \(String(describing: cell?.textLabel?.text))")
}
```